# Java printing out statement from right to left

Tags: java, eclipse

so I've been trying to figure this out but reached no success. So, I am suppose to create a program that prints out following triangle.

```
**********
 *********
  ******** 
   ******* 
    ******
     *****
      **** 
       ***  
        **  
         *
```

And here's my current code.

```
public class PatternC 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int len = 1;
        int k;

        System.out.println("**********");
        for (int row = 9; row > len; row--)
        {
    
            for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        for (int end = 0; end<1; end++)
        {
            System.out.format("%10s", "*");
        }
   }

}
```

But the program is printing out this!

```
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
         *
```

I did everything correctly, except I just need to align the middle stars to initially start from right to left. I've already tried print format, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just add the correct (increasing) number of spaces at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the spaces are throwing you off.

How would you print the following pattern?

```
**********
X*********
XX********
XXX*******
XXXX******
XXXXX*****
XXXXXX****
XXXXXXX***
XXXXXXXX**
XXXXXXXXX*
```

It's basically:

```
Print 0 X's, then 10 *'s
Print 1 X,   then  9 *'s
Print 2 X's, then  8 *'s
    .
    .
    .
Print 9 X's, then  1 *
```

Once you get that, replace "X" with a space character in your code, and you've got it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 6;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");              
            for(int j = 0; j < size - i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");              
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Here I am outputting i spaces, (in first row 0, in last size - 1),
and then size - i stars. (in first row size, in last 1);

Output:

```
******
 *****
  ****
   ***
    **
     *
```

Comment: `j <= i` should be `j < i`, the rest is fine.

Comment: ou, your right. i'll fix it

Comment: Thank you so much but I kinda used a different way. Yours work too!

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I have figured it out...

```
public class PatternC 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (i >= r)
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else if (i < r)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }       
}
```

And this was the output I got!

```
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *
```